# Can't run go file with go run (filename)

Tags: terminal, command-line

I just started getting into Golang and wanted to run a file in the terminal with go run and then the file name which is main.go

I configured the GOPATH like so:

```
export GOROOT="/usr/local/go"   
export GOPATH="/Users/myUsername/Desktop/gocode/"  
export PATH="/Users/myUsername/Desktop/gocode/bin:$PATH"
```

I created a folder on my desktop named gocode, placed three folders inside named src, pkg and bin.

And code is stored in src and when I want to run the code I get the following message.
my command was `go run main.go`
the output I received was  **stat main.go: no such file or directory**

I have no clue why it won't find the directory...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79562/discussion-on-question-by-spk888-cant-run-go-file-with-go-run-filename).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To *run* the `.go` file and not the compiled binary, you need to give `go run` the relative source file path. Try:

```
go run src/main.go
```

To *compile* the go program into a binary executable, use:

```
go build src/main.go
```

This will work if...

- `go` can be found; test this with the command `which go`. Does it return a path to `go`?
- Your `GOPATH` environment is set appropriately; test this with `echo $GOPATH`. Does it return the project directory? See [go wiki page on GOPATH](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GOPATH) for advice.

## Break Down the Problem

**Open a new Terminal.app window.** This will discard previous `export` commands that may be causing confusion.

**Test `go` can be found.** Use `which go` to ensure the binary is available. If not, fix this with an `export` command.

**Check the directory structure of your project.** Make sure no names are mispelt and your `.go` files have the correct suffix. The Finder may be hiding the true suffix. Does `ls -lR` list the contents you expect?

**Check you are in the right directory.** The `go` commands need to be executed from within the project directory. Use `pwd` to see what directory you are in? Is it the project directory `gocode/`? If not, use a `cd` command to fix this.

### Project Layout

Let's assume your file structure follows the minimal go convention:

```
gocode/
gocode/bin/
gocode/src/
gocode/src/main.go
```

The **three separate commands** to run `main.go` would be:

```
cd gocode
export GOPATH=$PWD
go run src/main.go
```

This will *run* the main function within `main.go`. To build an executable suitable for distribution, use the command `go build src/main.go`.

## Managing GOPATH Directories

With regard to managing gopaths and projects, I have had success with Herbert Fischer's [Manage multiple GOPATH dirs with ease](http://hgfischer.org/article/managing-multiple-gopaths/) approach.

Comment: I tried the two commends and both failed but the command `which go` returned the `go` path. The test with `echo $GOPATH` returned the project directory `/Users/myUsername` .

Comment: What does `echo $GOPATH` and `go version` return?

Comment: `go version` returns `go version go1.10.3 darwin/amd64`.

About the *Project Layout* I think the structure is the same I just have another folder called `pkg` in the folder `gocode`.
The command  
`cd gocode
export GOPATH=$PWD
go run src/main.go` does not run main.go for me.

Comment: Glad this helped. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers about how to accept an answer. Good luck with `go`, I find it a very productive language.